# How to remove cordova-plugin-compat?

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, cordova-ios

In the release notes of cordova-android 6.3.0 (https://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2017/09/27/android-release.html) it's written down that `cordova-plugin-compat` has to be removed

If I try

```
cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-compat
```

I get following error

> [ERROR] An error occurred while running cordova plugin remove
>   cordova-plugin-compat --save (exit code 1):
>
> Error: The plugin ‘cordova-plugin-compat’ is required by
>   (cordova-plugin-calendar, cordova-plugin-camera, cordova-plugin-file,
>   cordova-plugin-geolocation), skipping uninstallation. (try --force if
>   trying to update)

If I then try to `--force` the remove, it works, the plugin is removed and I'm able to build my android app.

BUT, I just removed my `iOS` platform to add it again and I face now the error

> cordova prepare ios Error: Cannot find plugin.xml for plugin "cordova-plugin-compat". Please try adding it again.
>
> [ERROR] An error occurred while running cordova prepare ios (exit code
>   1).

Any idea what am I doing wrong? Should really `cordova-plugin-compat` be removed? Why my iOS platform is referencing it, I thought it was only for android?

I use cordova-android@6.3.0 and cordova-ios@4.5.1

P.S.: If I remove and add the iOS platform, the compat plugin is automatically added as reference in package.json and package-lock.json

**UPDATE**

The last plugin release (https://cordova.apache.org/news/2017/11/10/plugins-release.html) most probably solve this issue respectively it looks like that the problem was the reference to the `cordova-plugin-compat` plugin from other plugin. But,

I'm not yet able to totally test it and solve it because I'm using another plugin where compat is also referenced (https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Calendar-PhoneGap-Plugin/issues/426).

I will keep this thread open till I could 100% confirm that this solve the referencing of compat.

**FINAL UPDATE**

The PR to remove the dependency from `Calendar-PhoneGap-Plugin` to ‘cordova-plugin-compat’ went thru, I was able to remove this last plugin without "force"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The source of the problem was that plugins were directly referencing `cordova-plugin-compat`.

Therefore, even if the use of the plugin was deprecated, it was still needed. Forcing a deletion (using --force) wasn't a solution, because if I removed and added a platform again, then, because of these references, the plugin ‘cordova-plugin-compat’ was automatically added again during that process.

The solution of the problem was then to wait for new releases or to submit PR to remove the dependency.

In my case there were the plugins which were referencing `cordova-plugin-compat`:

> Error: The plugin ‘cordova-plugin-compat’ is required by
>   (cordova-plugin-calendar, cordova-plugin-camera, cordova-plugin-file,
>   cordova-plugin-geolocation), skipping uninstallation. (try --force if
>   trying to update)

Updating following plugins solved my issue:

`cordova-plugin-camera@3.0.0`, `cordova-plugin-file@5.0.0` and `cordova-plugin-geolocation@3.0.0` removed the dependency (see https://cordova.apache.org/news/2017/11/10/plugins-release.html)

`cordova-plugin-calendar@5.0.0` removed the dependency thru this PR
https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Calendar-PhoneGap-Plugin/pull/430

Answer (score 2):

For me what fixed it was updating the Android SDK via Android Studio, then running:

```
cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-compat --force
cordova platform rm android
cordova platform add android@6.3.0
```

Hope that helps someone!

Comment: Did the same butit  doesn't worked for me since some of the plugins I use are still referencing directly the compat plugin

Comment: The --force should remove it even though it's being used by other plugins (I had the issue as well). Then when the "platform add" added them back, it attempted to re-add the plugin, but it denied the plugin because of the platform version. It worked fine for me, but one difference I did was i added the word ionic in front of each of the commands, because I'm using Ionic.

Comment: Yep I did that too and it works for Android, but if you remove/add the iOS platform, the compat gonna be added again I think

Answer (score 0):

The cordova-plugin-compat is for Android only so it should not cause errors for iOS. I suggest to try to clean your Cordova project.

Delete the following directories : plugins, platforms, node_modules. They will be recreated

Then execute :

```
cordova platform add android
cordova platform add ios
cordova prepare # usually made by commands above but juste in case
cordova compile
```

Comment: I did fully delete the compat plugins and I fully removed both platforms and added them again which lead me to the error

Comment: Is the plugin still referenced in package.json or config.xml ?

Comment: config.xml I'm 100% sure it wasn't referenced anymore. package.json most probably but I didn't remember checking it...maybe will give a try next week again and double check this

Comment: cordova-plugin-compat requirement seems to be removed in cordova-geolocation 3.0.0 dev version see: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-geolocation/commit/642a2f35d4df90e9d5929dc5eb2f9bbdb6ad5dbf hopefully this version will be released soon :)

Answer (score 0):

You probably have another plugin that is requiring the compat plugin. Check your plugins' package.json for this.

Comment: Yes of course, the warning tells that (cordova-plugin-calendar, cordova-plugin-camera, cordova-plugin-file, cordova-plugin-geolocation) but compat is now included in cordova-android and the release notes stated that compat should be removed

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with cordova-plugin-file is there a solution for now?

https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/cordova-plugin-file-cordova-android-6-3-0-build-error/110682

Answer (score 0):

remove plugin compat older than version 1.2

```
$ cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-compat --force
```

then add version 1.2

```
$ cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-compat@1.2
```

This worked handsomely well for me!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I didn't even need to remove `cordova-plugin-compat`, as [it's included in Cordova 6.3](https://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2017/09/27/android-release.html). Then, plugins that required it as a dependency were still working.